# How to pass data to instance of UITabBarController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` on storyboard,  the corresponding Swift class is named **MyTabBarController.swift** I have an data variable in that class:

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    var myData: MyData?
    ...
}
```

I start this tab bar controller programmatically from **another controller** by:

```
let myTabBarStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myTabBar", bundle: Bundle.main)

let myTabBarController = myTabBarStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"myTabBarController") as! UITabBarController // I can't cast it to MyTabBarController, because it would raise runtime error of type casting

 // now I have a data prepared for `myTabBarController` instance
 let data = prepareMyData()

// how can pass data to myTabBarController now? like I said above, the type casting to MyTabBarController is not allowed
present(myTabBarController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

My question is in the comment of above code, how to pass data to `myTabBarController`?

(I would like to set the data to `myTabBarController` so that data can be accessed/shared by all view controllers hosted by the tab bar controller)

Comment: If you need data to be shared across all your controllers that are hosted by the tab bar controller I would not store it in the tab bar controller. Obviously without more context I could be wrong but might I suggest having a manager class of some sort deal with the managing the data? And then every other controller can just get/set from the manager. Just a suggestion of mine without knowing the entire scope of the project.

Comment: Thanks @TPN1994, if I go with your suggestion, should the data manager better be a singleton?

Comment: It completely depends on what you need but In my case mine are all singleton. (And I believe this will be the case more often than not because of the very nature of apps)

Comment: I actually have the same idea that using singleton to manage data in order to share across view controllers, but I was not sure whether it is a good practice in iOS, but now, I think I will use it, thank you very much.

Comment: Just to add, the beauty of having a singleton/manager handle that data instead of the tab bar controller is that if for some reason you wanted to change the tab bar controller to something else it would be trivial to do so in terms of managing the data. Also makes getting/setting the data cleaner as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to cast to `MyTabBarController`, it means you have not set the correct type in Interface Builder.

After you fix that, cast to `MyTabBarController` and you will have access to `myData` on that instance.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. One followup question, is it fine in general share data among view controllers hosted by `myTabBarController` in this way?

Answer (score 0):

This will not give you an error if your storyboard has wrong reference. Also, this will work perfectly and you can set data, if your storyboard reference is correct.

```
let myTabBarStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myTabBar", bundle: Bundle.main)
if let myTabBarController = myTabBarStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"myTabBarController") as? MyTabBarController {

  myTabBarController.myData = prepareMyData()
 present(myTabBarController, animated:true, completion: nil)

} else {
  print("Storyboard has wrong reference...")
}
```